# Typecasting a pointer to change its size (in bytes)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, uint8t

I'm trying to use pointers to move through a region of memory filled with hexadecimal values. I'm using a uint8_t pointer to ensure that it only points to 1 byte at a time. I want to go to a specific location (Offset number of bytes from the starting location) and store a group of bytes that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length. I then want to interpret and print the value as either a signed or unsigned decimal (determined by an enum parameter).

I thought that I could go simply change the pointer from a 1-byte uint8_t to the correct size for the number of bytes (eg. uint64_t for 8 btyes) and then store the value (because I can't just print it one byte at a time, I need to evaluate the whole byte/group of bytes). This is what I have so far:

```
void showValueAtOffset(FILE* Out, const uint8_t* const baseAddr, uint32_t Offset, Sign Sgn, uint8_t nBytes) {//------------------doesn't work----------------
   uint8_t *p = baseAddr;//create a pointer that points to the first byte of memory in the array
   for(int i = 0; i < Offset; i++){//use a for loop to move p to the location indicated by Offset 
       p++;
   }
   if(nBytes == 1){
       //pointer p already has the correct typecast for the number of bytes
       uint8_t N = *p;//store the value of the byte
       if(Sgn == SIGNED){
           int8_t result = N;
           fprintf(Out, "%d  ", result);//print the value
       }
       else{//if UNSIGNED
           fprintf(Out, "%u  ", N);//print the value
       }
   }
   else if(nBytes == 2){
       uint16_t q = (uint16_t) p;//create the pointer q with the correct typecast for the number of bytes
       uint16_t N = *q;//store the value of the bytes
       if(Sgn == SIGNED){
           int16_t result = N;
           fprintf(Out, "%d  ", result);//print the value
       }
       else{//if UNSIGNED
           fprintf(Out, "%u  ", N);//print the value
       }
   }
   else if(nBytes == 4){
       uint32_t q = (uint32_t) p;//create the pointer q with the correct typecast for the number of bytes
       uint32_t N = *q;//store the value of the bytes
       if(Sgn == SIGNED){
           int32_t result = N;
           fprintf(Out, "%d  ", result);//print the value
       }
       else{//if UNSIGNED
           fprintf(Out, "%u  ", N);//print the value
       }
   }
   else if(nBytes == 8){
       uint64_t q = (uint64_t) p;//create the pointer q with the correct typecast for the number of bytes
       uint64_t N = *q;//store the value of the bytes
       if(Sgn == SIGNED){
           signed int result = (signed int) N;
           fprintf(Out, "%d  ", result);//print the value
       }
       else{//if UNSIGNED
            unsigned int result = (unsigned int) N;
            fprintf(Out, "%u  ", result);//print the value
       }
   }
   else{
       //this should not happen according to the preconditions
   }
   fprintf(Out, "\n");
}
```

This does not work, and I get several errors like "invalid type arguement 'unary *' (have 'uint32_t')" and "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are converting a `uint8_t *` into a `uint32_t` (for example), losing the pointiness of the type.  You would still have to worry about alignment of pointers.  On many machines, you either cannot use a `uint64_t *` if it not pointing at an 8-byte boundary (the address is not a multiple of 8), or you get a fairly severe slowdown in the access. (For example, in a DEC Alpha, an unaligned access triggered a system call which could fix things up for you, but was vastly, vastly slower than an aligned access which typically did not need a system call at all.)

Comment: Note that the title of the question is misguided.  You can't change the size of a pointer; for practical purposes, all data pointers are the same size as each other regardless of what they point to.  What you can change is the size of object that is pointed at.  As noted previously, there are caveats about what you can do, but if the winds is fair, you can change cast the value stored in a `uint8_t *` into a value stored in a `uint64_t *` and then use the resulting pointer to fetch 64 bits (8 bytes) of data in a single operation.

Comment: Ok, I added an * inside the typecasts (uint32_t*) and all of them are working now except for the 8-byte part (the one with the uint64_t's).

When I look at the results, it looks like the value is being truncated to a 32-bit integer instead of a 64-bit integer. I assume that this is happening because I cast it as a 'signed int'  and 'unsigned int' before printing it.
What should I cast it as to keep the 64-bit size and print it correctly?

Comment: You should use the macros from `<inttypes.h>`; in this case `PRId64` contains the correct information for printing a signed value (`int64_t`) in decimal and `PRIu64` for printing an unsigned value (`uint64_t`) in decimal.  You pass a value of the correct type to `printf()`, of course.

Comment: I figured it out by casting it as a long long int. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That'll work in the short term, but isn't guaranteed to be reliable in the long term (though it's a bit hard to envisage what would make it break; even if `long long` is 128 bits, converting `uint64_t` to 128 bits wouldn't do any direct harm).  But the formal conversion specifiers for `uint64_t` and `int64_t` are the PRI*64 values in `<inttypes.h>`.  Since your variable is a `uint64_t`, if you use those and simply pass the `uint64_t` value, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate source of errors is that you should use `uint16_t *q = (uint16_t *) p;`, not `uint16_t q = (uint16_t) p;`, that is typecast a pointer type to another pointer type and later resolve it.

Still, the modified code is machine architecture dependent, there are issues of big/little-endian and alignment. In short, the code will work on an x86 box, but may crash due to unaligned memory access or produce wrong numbers on other architectures. A portable way would be something like this:

```
uint32_t to_uint32_be(const void* num)
{
    const uint8_t *p = num;
    uint32_t res = 0U;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        res = (res << 8) + p[i];
    return res;
}
```

In the code above 'be' stands for big-endian, that is, data is stored in the network byte order with the most significant byte first.